# Spring @RequestParam null when sending Parameter in form-data

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In my controller when sending parameter as form-data, its receiving as `null` value.
 When passing parameter as `x-www-form-urlencoded`, I am getting the value.
My controller is like the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getid", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ServerResponse id(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) String id) {...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to send parameters are form-data then you need to add support for this in Spring,
Have a look at spring's documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart

> Spring’s built-in multipart support handles file uploads in web
>   applications. You enable this multipart support with pluggable
>   MultipartResolver objects, defined in the
>   org.springframework.web.multipart package. Spring provides one
>   MultipartResolver implementation for use with Commons FileUpload and
>   another for use with Servlet 3.0 multipart request parsing.
>
> By default, Spring does no multipart handling, because some developers
>   want to handle multiparts themselves. You enable Spring multipart
>   handling by adding a multipart resolver to the web application’s
>   context. Each request is inspected to see if it contains a multipart.
>   If no multipart is found, the request continues as expected. If a
>   multipart is found in the request, the MultipartResolver that has been
>   declared in your context is used. After that, the multipart attribute
>   in your request is treated like any other attribute.

This is an example of how to use CommonsMultipartResolver

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

    <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000"/>

</bean>
```

> Of course you also need to put the appropriate jars in your classpath
>   for the multipart resolver to work. In the case of the
>   CommonsMultipartResolver, you need to use commons-fileupload.jar.